# Is there a difference between SIMO and MISO, i.e. does it matter whether the transmitter or receiver is the multipath device?

Tags: wireless

On this [article about various MIMO schemes](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/antennas/mimo/formats-siso-simo-miso-mimo.php), SIMO (Single Input Multiple Output, i.e. the ) and MISO (Multiple Input Single Output) are both mentioned as possible combinations where one device has multiple antennas, but the other does not. The only difference the article mentions between the two schemes is that they shift the additional processing burden required for multiple propagation onto different ends of the link - SIMO has the receiver handle this, while MISO has the transmitter do this.

Beyond additional processing burden, are there any other performance differences between having the transmitter vs. having the receiver as the multipath device? Say I have a transceiver A, which is multipath, and another transceiver B, which is not. Assuming identical output power and sensitivity levels, if I begin transmitting from A to B, will the performance of the link be identical as if I began transmitting from B to A?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is largely dependent on your two locations, available antenna configurations, and application. The article talks about how two antenna can be used at the receiver to circumvent fading in shortwave transmissions. Two antenna at the transmitter may not have the same affect.

Another area where this may be important is when dealing with antenna polarization. Example you may have a base station and a moving vehicle. Lets say this vehicle can move in 3 dimensions. In that case you may want a single antenna (isotropic or directional) on the ground while two perpendicular antenna on the vehicle.

MIMO may also be used due to size restrictions. you may be able to have a large high gain antenna at one station, but only space for two smaller low gain antenna at the other.

In short the performance of the link is dependent on antenna configuration. Maybe read further about antenna diversity. Here may be a starter article http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1273367

One other thing to keep in mind is that two TX antennas means that the signal can travel further and be read by more receivers, whilst two RX antennas means that the receiver may have more range and be able to listen to more stations.